# Amazon S3 - uploading file with the same name is not overwriting the object

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading a file with a specific name, when a tried to upload another file with the same name is not overwriting the file.
Instead I am able to access to the new file using this url:
https://applider.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/questions/section-1/level-1/question-3/M1.N1.E3-1.1.1.png

The link what returns the s3 upload method is this one:
https://applider.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assets/questions/section-1/level-1/question-3/M1.N1.E3-1.1.1.png

The link with "us-west-2" returns the previous file and the link without "us-west-2" returns the new file.

I tried deleting the object but the link with "us-west-2" is still active and has the previous file and the link without "us-west-2" is not active anymore when I delete the object

Comment: Are you using the stated URLs to access these files or something else? The URLs would only work if the objects were public.

Comment: Sounds like you might have some content cached in your browser. Does it behave this way from a different browser?